# kernel.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `memset'

Tags: c, kernel, ld

I am writing a custom kernel, but I am getting an error when linking. I have taken the code and broken it down, but still no luck. Here's my code:

kernel.c:

```
#include <string.h>
// define our structure
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
    unsigned short di, si, bp, sp, bx, dx, cx, ax;
    unsigned short gs, fs, es, ds, eflags;
} regs16_t;

// tell compiler our int32 function is external
extern void int32(unsigned char intnum, regs16_t *regs);

// int32 test
void int32_test()
{
    int y;
    regs16_t regs;

    // switch to 320x200x256 graphics mode
    regs.ax = 0x0013;
    int32(0x10, &regs);

    // full screen with blue color (1)
    memset((char *)0xA0000, 1, (320*200));

    // draw horizontal line from 100,80 to 100,240 in multiple colors
    for(y = 0; y < 200; y++)
        memset((char *)0xA0000 + (y*320+80), y, 160);

    // wait for key
    regs.ax = 0x0000;
    int32(0x16, &regs);

    // switch to 80x25x16 text mode
    regs.ax = 0x0003;
    int32(0x10, &regs);
}
```

kernel.asm:

```
[bits 32]

global int32, _int32

struc regs16_t
    .di resw 1
    .si resw 1
    .bp resw 1
    .sp resw 1
    .bx resw 1
    .dx resw 1
    .cx resw 1
    .ax resw 1
    .gs resw 1
    .fs resw 1
    .es resw 1
    .ds resw 1
    .ef resw 1
endstruc

%define INT32_BASE 0x7C00
%define REBASE(x) (((x) - reloc) + INT32_BASE)
%define GDTENTRY(x) ((x) << 3)
%define CODE32 GDTENTRY(1)
%define DATA32 GDTENTRY(2)
%define CODE16 GDTENTRY(3)
%define DATA16 GDTENTRY(4)
%define STACK16 (INT32_BASE - regs16_t_size)

extern int32_test

global start

section .text
    align 4
    dd 0x1BADB002
    dd 0x00
    dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x00)

    int32: use32                            
    _int32:
        cli                                 
        pusha                               
        mov  esi, reloc                     
        mov  edi, INT32_BASE                
        mov  ecx, (int32_end - reloc)       
        cld                                 
        rep  movsb                          
        jmp INT32_BASE                      
    reloc: use32                            
        mov  [REBASE(stack32_ptr)], esp     
        sidt [REBASE(idt32_ptr)]            
        sgdt [REBASE(gdt32_ptr)]            
        lgdt [REBASE(gdt16_ptr)]            
        lea  esi, [esp+0x24]                
        lodsd                               
        mov  [REBASE(ib)], al               
        mov  esi, [esi]                     
        mov  edi, STACK16                   
        mov  ecx, regs16_t_size             
        mov  esp, edi                       
        rep  movsb                          
        jmp  word CODE16:REBASE(p_mode16)   
    p_mode16: use16
        mov  ax, DATA16                     
        mov  ds, ax                         
        mov  es, ax                         
        mov  fs, ax                         
        mov  gs, ax                         
        mov  ss, ax                         
        mov  eax, cr0                       
        and  al,  ~0x01                     
        mov  cr0, eax                       
        jmp  word 0x0000:REBASE(r_mode16)   
    r_mode16: use16
        xor  ax, ax                         
        mov  ds, ax                         
        mov  ss, ax                         
        lidt [REBASE(idt16_ptr)]            
        mov  bx, 0x0870                     
        call resetpic                       
        popa                                
        pop  gs                             
        pop  fs                             
        pop  es                             
        pop  ds                             
        sti                                 
        db 0xCD                             
    ib: db 0x00
        cli                                 
        xor  sp, sp                         
        mov  ss, sp                         
        mov  sp, INT32_BASE                 
        pushf                               
        push ds                             
        push es                             
        push fs                             
        push gs                             
        pusha                               
        mov  bx, 0x2028                     
        call resetpic                       
        mov  eax, cr0                       
        inc  eax                            
        mov  cr0, eax                       
        jmp  dword CODE32:REBASE(p_mode32)  
    p_mode32: use32
        mov  ax, DATA32                 
        mov  ds, ax                     
        mov  es, ax                     
        mov  fs, ax                     
        mov  gs, ax                     
        mov  ss, ax                     
        lgdt [REBASE(gdt32_ptr)]        
        lidt [REBASE(idt32_ptr)]        
        mov  esp, [REBASE(stack32_ptr)] 
        mov  esi, STACK16               
        lea  edi, [esp+0x28]            
        mov  edi, [edi]                 
        mov  ecx, regs16_t_size         
        cld                             
        rep  movsb                      
        popa                            
        sti                             
        ret                             

    resetpic:                           
        push ax                         
        mov  al, 0x11                   
        out  0x20, al                   
        out  0xA0, al                   
        mov  al, bh                     
        out  0x21, al                   
        mov  al, bl                     
        out  0xA1, al                   
        mov  al, 0x04                   
        out  0x21, al                   
        shr  al, 1                      
        out  0xA1, al                   
        shr  al, 1                      
        out  0x21, al                   
        out  0xA1, al                   
        pop  ax                         
        ret                             

    stack32_ptr:                        
        dd 0x00000000                   

    idt32_ptr:                          
        dw 0x0000                       
        dd 0x00000000                   

    gdt32_ptr:                          
        dw 0x0000                       
        dd 0x00000000                   

    idt16_ptr:                          
        dw 0x03FF                       
        dd 0x00000000                   

    gdt16_base:                         
        .null:                          
            dd 0x00000000               
            dd 0x00000000               

        .code32:                        
            dw 0xFFFF                   
            dw 0x0000                   
            db 0x00                     
            db 0x9A                     
            db 0xCF                     
            db 0x00                     

        .data32:                        
            dw 0xFFFF                   
            dw 0x0000                   
            db 0x00                     
            db 0x92                     
            db 0xCF                     
            db 0x00                     

        .code16:                        
            dw 0xFFFF                   
            dw 0x0000                   
            db 0x00                     
            db 0x9A                     
            db 0x0F                     
            db 0x00                     

        .data16:
            dw 0xFFFF
            dw 0x0000
            db 0x00
            db 0x92
            db 0x0F
            db 0x00

    gdt16_ptr:
        dw gdt16_ptr - gdt16_base - 1
        dd gdt16_base

    int32_end:

start:
    call int32_test
    hlt
```

link.ld:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
 {
   . = 0x100000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
 }
```

Command Line & Output:

```
# gcc -fno-stack-protector -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o
# nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kasm.o
# ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
kc.o: In function `int32_test':
kernel.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `memset'
kernel.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `memset'
```

A little bit of background:
I am working on a custom OS for a custom project that I call AI Glasses. I am currently building a bootloader that will show a logo and some loading indicator. I am thinking that my indicator will be sort of like on Ubuntu. Anyways, I need to be able to go into a VGA mode and display stuff on the screen, while the rest of my (future) code can boot it up fully.

My question:
How do I import memset's lib into my code so that ld can fully link my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that linker doesn't find memset function in the object files you provide to ld. Neither kasm.o nor kc.o seem to have this function. In fact this is part of standard C library. So, you need to link standard C library, libc.so or libc.a. If you don't want to use standard C library in your kernel, you will need to provide your own implementation of memset

Comment: How do I link the standard C library?

Comment: try to add libc.a to ld call

Comment: Where is libc.a located on the latest Ubuntu?

Comment: should be available in /usr/lib

Comment: I don't see libc.a in /usr/lib. How do I install it?

Comment: it is definitely installed. Try different places. /usr/share/lib,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu etc.

sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc libc6 libc6-dev

Comment: find -O10 | grep libc.a only stated "./usr/libx32/libc.a ./usr/lib32/libc.a"

Comment: Nevermind, I used libc.so from /usr/lib32 and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Most library functions, including `memset`, are not available in kernel modules.

You'll need to create your own implementation.  It should be as simple as a single `for` loop.  Since you're also writing some assembly, you may want to try writing it that way.

Comment: Please expand on how I should go about creating my own implementation. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaronjam Create a function called `memset`, and have it loop through the bytes setting the given value.

Comment: @Aaronjam if you are not able to write a simple `memcpy` function, I'm not sure if writing a custom kernel is something for you.